# android glsurfaceview null pointer exception

Tags: android

I got this error. Any idea ?

```
12-29 22:24:46.087: WARN/dalvikvm(2307): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:471)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:532)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:339)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-29 22:24:46.147: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 22:24:46.167: WARN/ActivityManager(57):   Force finishing activity com.kamil.cakir/.ResimEgici
12-29 22:24:46.667: WARN/ActivityManager(57): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43fc5250 com.kamil.cakir/.ResimEgici}
```

Comment: showing `LogCat` logs don't really give anyone a chance at giving an exact answer to your question.  show some code so people can view and work through it

Comment: Sure, you have a null pointer exception somewhere in your code

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the solution. I had a GLSurfaceView class implementing the Renderer interface. I have forgotton to set the renderer into my glview.

```
class CustomGl extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer{

    SquareImage image;
    Context context;
    float rquad = 0.0f;
    public CustomGl(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, null);


        //Set this as Renderer
        this.setRenderer(this);    //**I ADDED THIS THE PROBLEM SOLVED!**


        this.context = context;
        this.image = new SquareImage();
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "gl const");
    }
```